# Accessing classes from other classes and in functions PHP

Tags: php, class, oop, variables, global

I've not written OOP code before, I always tried to avoid the extra keystrokes. Anyway, I'm taking the plunge as it's supposed to increase readability.

Anyway, I'm having trouble getting my classes to be able to access each other's methods.

Here's my setup:

```
$conf = new Conf(); // boot up!

// Include dependencies, system files and other functions
require_once $conf->getIncludePath() . 'error.php';
require_once $conf->getIncludePath() . 'pool.php';
require_once $conf->getIncludePath() . 'database.php';
require_once $conf->getIncludePath() . 'api.php';
require_once $conf->getIncludePath() . 'user.php';
require_once $conf->getIncludePath() . 'forms.php';
require_once $conf->getIncludePath() . 'page.php';
require_once $conf->getIncludePath() . 'resources.php';

$error = new Error();
$pool = new Pool();
$db = new Database();
$api = new Api();
$user = new User();
$forms = new Forms();
$page = new Page();
$resources = new Resources();
```

My question is, how do I get it so that a method in `User` class can run the query method inside `Database`, to say fetch their information?

I'm aware of using `global $db; global $user; etc.` inside every method ever, but isn't there a way for me to get to these variables without having to essentially redeclare them every time I want to use them?

Thanks

Piers

Comment: Try to read something about OOP patterns before writing code. It'll give you idea what is it all for.

Comment: Dependency Injection is pretty useful at times like this... but read up about autoloading, please

Comment: dont use oop style for readability. oop (as far as my knowledge is concerned) is about code re-usability, encapsulation and other object oriented paradigms. but [dependency injection](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/dependency-injection-in-php/) is what you need

Comment: I'd suggest the gang of 5 design patterns book to see what OOP can do.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I looked at dependency injection but it looks like I'd have to manually inject every other dependency into every object and was looking for a more modular/configurable/automated system. The only reason I've split up the different objects is because I read somewhere that an object is a group of functions relating to the same resource/idea/feature and obviously this is causing problems.

Comment: I've found an excellent example showing really simplified ways of creating a dependency system [link](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/dependency-injection-huh/). This is just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Using objects is *so* much more than just readability.

Without going into a full blown explanation of the reasons behind this, I highly recommend further research into the topic. Starting with **why** they are used and the problems that they resolve (and cause!).

As for your question:

You have a large number of objects that should really be able to 'talk' to each other. 
We could say that the `User` class is *dependent* on the `Database`. To resolve this dependency we need to be able to reference the `Database` in the context on the `User` (the correct *scope*).

There are a few ways to accomplish this, however the common practice would be to define a member variable inside the `User` class and the set the value of the property using setters and getters. This is known to be [injecting the dependencies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

For example:

```
class User {
 protected $database;

 public function getDatabase()
 {
  return $this->database;
 }     

 public function setDatabase(Database $database) {
  $this->database = $database;
 }

 public function getUsers()
 {
   $sql = 'SELECT * FROM user';
   return $this->getDatabase()->execute($sql);
 }
}
```

Your client code would then become:

```
$db = new Database();
$user = new User();
$user->setDatabase($db);
```

Please note that the above example is a contrived one at best - Making the `User` class depending on the `Database` would be a design decision that will cause you other problems further down the line - Something I think you need to research into.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestions, but considering that I'll need to inject pretty much every class into every other class (pages display resources and contain forms that submit user data via the api into the database), I was hoping for a system that meant I could add/remove dependencies easily (like working from an array of dependency filenames or something)...

Answer (score 1):

### Use dependency injection!

You could create a new class, `DBHandler`, that stores an *instance* of your `Database` class into every other class you want.

For example:

```
class DBHandler {

  public static $db;
 
  public static function init($db) {
    self::$db = $db;
  }
}
```

---

```
$db = new Database();
DBHandler::init($db);
```

Then you just need to *inherit* from this class, by using the `extends` keyword.

i.e.:

```
class User extends DBHandler {
  // ... your code here ...
}
```

This is an example of how you could implement the [dependency injection](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/dependency-injection-in-php/).

---

### The __autoload() function

You don't need to `require` a class everytime you need if you use the [`__autoload()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.autoload.php) function.

For example, you can do this to automatically resolve dependencies:

```
function __autoload($classname) {
  require_once $classname . ".php";
}
```

Comment: does autoload detect new instances of any class and automatically require it? because this might be a step in the right direction (idk)

Comment: Yes it does. `__autoload()` will be called whenever you attempt to use an undefined class.

Answer (score 0):

Following the tutorial at [nettuts+](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/dependency-injection-huh/) lead me to write this:

```
// load configuration
require_once 'includes/class.conf.php';
$conf = new Conf(dirname(__FILE__));

// dependency class
$conf->registerRequiredFile('dependencies');
$dependencies = new Dependencies();

// start registering dependencies
$conf->registerRequiredFile('error');
$error = $dependencies->error = function(){ // error
    $error = new Error();
    $error->conf = $conf;
    return $error;
};

$conf->registerRequiredFile('pool');
$pool = $dependencies->pool = function(){ // error
    $pool = new Pool();
    $pool->db = $db;
    $pool->user = $user;
    $pool->error = $error;
    // etc. any other dependencies
    return $pool;
};
```

It works perfectly, the first conf file contains the registerRequiredFile method that then require_once a uri based on the parameter given.

Thanks for your help in pointing me in the right direction!